# A partition of the set of non-eventual-constant sequences by left translation

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory

Suppose, $A \subset 2^{\omega}$ is the set of all non-eventual-constant sequences, which means, for an arbitary sequence $\{a_i\}_{i \in \omega}$ in $A$, there doesn't exist $k$ such that for all $ n > k$, $a_n = a_k$.

Define $\operatorname{S}$ as left translation, that is, if $x = \{b_i\}_{i \in \omega}$, $\operatorname{S}{x} = \{c_i\}_{i \in \omega}$, then $c_i = b_{i+1}$.

Is there a non-empty subset $B$ of $A$, such that for all $y \in A$, if $y \in B$, then $\operatorname{S}{y} \in A \setminus B$?

Comment: You could take $B = \varnothing$ but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: @Lord_Farin:Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any subset of $B=\{(x_i)\in A\mid\forall i: x_{2i}=0\}$. Note that because $B\subseteq A$ every sequence in $B$ must have infinitely many odd indices with $1$, therefore their translation would have to have infinitely many even indices with $1$, and therefore is not an element of $B$.

You can perhaps even extend this $B$ by setting "eventually zero on even coordinates".